# Remove the last two Characters in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need to remove the last the last two characters of all cells found in a worksheet named `Target` with the column name `Order` (column BD).

This macro below would have looked in row 1 Worksheet Target for the word `orders`. It then would have removed the last two characters (strings).

However since I am new and got these macros from two different sources I likely messed up in assigning variables.

```
Sub RemoveOrdersTT()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim lastCol As Long
  Dim i As Long

  Set ws = Worksheets("Target")
  With ws
     lastCol = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
      For i = 1 To lastCol
       If InStr(1, UCase(.Cells(1, i).Value), "Orders") > 0 Then
         .Cells(1, i).Value = Left(.Cells(1, i).Value, Len(.Cells(1, i).Value) - 2)
        End If
      Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

A code that would look at worksheet `Target` and column BD starting at row 2 or a fix to my code would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. In column BD "Orders" every order number will have TT at the end (i.e row 2: 123TT, row 3: 345TT). I am trying to remove the TT.

Answer (score 1):

Change the inner if:

```
If InStr(1, UCase(.Cells(1, i).Value), "ORDER") > 0 Then
  .cells(1,i).value = left(.cells(1,i).value, Len(.cells(1,i).value) -2)
End If
```

1. InStr requires 3 parameters (plus some optional ones), you were missing the first parm telling it where to start looking
2. In the `If` statement, InStr will return a position or 0, so testing for `> 0` is sufficient, no need for `<>`, though that will work, it's just unnecessary
3. Remove the 2nd call to `UCase()` in the `if` statement itself, no need to `UCase` a fixed string, just provide it in upper case.
4. No need to mess with trying to create another range object and modifying that, you've already got the cell you need.

**Also:**

Assuming your data is rectangular (i.e. you don't have any columns without headers that you don't want to have searched):

```
LastCol = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

Is a much easier way of finding out how many columns are in use, and doesn't require moving the active cell about the worksheet.

**Complete Code**

```
Sub RemoveOrdersTT()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim lastCol As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim r as long

  Set ws = Worksheets("Target")
  With ws
     lastCol = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
      For i = 1 To lastCol
       If InStr(1, UCase(.Cells(1, i).Value), "Orders") > 0 Then
         for r = 2 to .usedRange.Rows.Count
           .Cells(r, i).Value = Left(.Cells(r, i).Value, Len(.Cells(r,i).Value) - 2)
         next
        End If
      Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

Had to add the inner loop `For r...` to actually get it to traverse the rows in that column

Comment: I posted the changes you suggested in the original post. I ran this code and it once took off two characters from the column name (found in row 1). It did not remove anything from the cells under it. I tried the code again and it did nothing.

Comment: I am getting Invalid Procedure call or argument at line 14 or `.Cells(r, i).Value = Left(.Cells(r, i).Value, Len(.Cells(r, i).Value) - 2)`. However it does work! Any suggestions. I was going to put `On Error Resume Next` but I am not sure that is what we need.